# Not able to parse string object created from appending characters

Tags: c++, file, getline, stringstream

I am appending character read through the file in string object (str) and after that
when tried to search the string (Title:) from the string object (str) then able to print only the search string, not the entire string (Title: John).

```
 std::string str;
 char ch;
 while (ch != EOF)
 {
        putc(ch, stdout);
        ch = getc(fp);
        str+=ch1;
 }

 std::string T; 
 std::stringstream X(str); 
 std::string infoString {""} ;
 while (std::getline(X, infoString ))
 {      

    if (infoString.find("Title: ", 0, 14) != std::string::npos)
    {
      std::cout<<infoString<<std::endl;
    } 
                         
 }
```

Here is the `infoString` output :
`Title:`

Expected output:
`Title:  John`

Here is the file content :
`Title:  John`

Comment: What's in `str` after your first loop? Did it properly read in the whole file?

Comment: Why do you need to construct a stringstream from a string, then extract the string from the stringstream, then search it, instead of searching the original string?

Comment: Is there something stopping you from using `std::fstream`?

Comment: ... and what is `ch1`, exactly?

Comment: `char ch; while (ch != EOF)` it is undefined behavior compare `ch` with `EOF` before `ch` is initialized

Comment: str is getting printed [Title: John] properly

Comment: I need to construct a stringsteam from a string in order to avoid compilation error. template argument deduction/substitution failed: